# Grep Git Branch Names, Return Only Branches Whose Name Contain "Theme"

Tags: git, grep, git-branch

If I have a list of 48 remote branches for a repo, I can do

```
git branch -a
```

To list all of them, how do I `grep` through those to only return the ones whose name contains `Theme`?

Answer (score 39):

Just use the pipe operator (|):

```
git branch -a | grep Theme
```

Comment: Careful when using this inside a script. The output looks like:
    `* Theme
      remotes/origin/Theme`

The `*` character can be greedy. The result we had was our script ended up including files in addition to branches.

A fix from my colleague looked like: `git branch -a | tr '*' ' ' | grep Theme`

Comment: `git branch -a | tr -d * | grep Theme`

Comment: Do a `git fetch` first.
Its best to update your remote-tracking branches before searching. Got bitten by this one since I was trying to search for a remote branch that I knew existed, but it wasn't showing up -.-

Answer (score 33):

No need to use `grep`. You can just use `git branch --list <pattern>` where `<pattern>` can contain wildcards:

```
git branch --all --list *Theme*
```

The `--all` option will include [remote branches](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches) in the search.

Comment: Keep in mind, `*` doesn't match empty string. E.g. `*Theme*` won't match `Theme`, but would match `SomeThemeStuff`.

Answer (score 10):

You could pipe the output to grep.

```
git branch -a | grep Theme
```

Comment: How to pass this result to checkout?
I'm trying
**git branch | grep '17' | git checkout**
but something wrong with message like branch-name should be specified.

Answer (score 4):

Git branch is more of a ui command... to get output that you can reasonably process you can use `git for-each-ref`:

```
git for-each-ref --format '%(refname:short)' refs/heads # Local
git for-each-ref --format '%(refname:short)' refs/remotes # Remote
```